# SQL Server error log entry : Error: 17806, Severity: 20, State: 14

Tags: sql-server

I have error in my log for a few weeks, I searched a lot but I couldn't found useful answer.

I did closed SQL Server port for public IP, but I have problem yet.

> Error: 17806, Severity: 20, State: 14.
>   SSPI handshake failed with error code 0x8009030c, state 14 while establishing a connection with integrated security; the connection has been closed. Reason: AcceptSecurityContext failed. The Windows error code indicates the cause of failure. The logon attempt failed [CLIENT: 10.10.3.25]
>
> Time raised: 27 Jan 2015 2:23 PM

It was raised error while this system was off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any time I have seen this error in my environment (0x8009030c and State 14), it has been because the SQL Server engine account was running with a Domain service account, and that account was locked at the time a Kerberos connection was attempted.  The connection would work, but it would be kicked down to NTLM.

Method 1:

1. Go to register  start –> run … Regedit
2. Go to:  HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\LSA
3. Add a DWORD value called “DisableLoopbackCheck”
4. Set this value to 1
5. Rebooted after making this change.

After this registry change was effected.

Method 2. This somehow worked for me: Restarting the sql browser services:

Also, for more info on the related issue, refer to below article:

http://www.allenkinsel.com/archive/2010/06/sql-server-and-sspi-handshake-failed-error-hell/

Comment: Can i refer this problem to my network admin? is this a network issue or a sql server issue. Is there any other way other then changing the registry ? Can i safely ignore this error ?